# Spark JSON Schema for dynamic key fields?

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I receive JSON data from kafka with `from_json()` method. It expects schema from me. My JSON structure like this;

```
{
    "Items": {
        "key1": [
            {
                "id": "",
                "name": "",
                "val": ""
            }
        ],
        "key2": [
            {
                "id": "",
                "name": "",
                "val": ""
            }
        ],
        "key3": [
            {
                "id": "",
                "name": "",
                "val": ""
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

In this state; `key1, key2, key3` fields are unknown. So, they are `dynamic`. These fields name may be `"abc", "def"` etc.. How can I define json schema for this JSON in Spark Structured Streaming?

**EDIT:**
For example another json;

```
{
        "Items": {
            "stack": [
                {
                    "id": "",
                    "name": "",
                    "val": ""
                }
            ],
            "over": [
                {
                    "id": "",
                    "name": "",
                    "val": ""
                }
            ],
            "flow": [
                {
                    "id": "",
                    "name": "",
                    "val": ""
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define your schema to parse such json files. Your schema should look like this.

```
val valSchema = new StructType()
  .add("id", StringType)
  .add("name", StringType)
  .add("val", StringType)

val valArrSchema = new ArrayType(valSchema, true)
val mapSchema = new MapType(StringType, valArrSchema, true)
val jsonSchema =  new StructType().add("Items", mapSchema)
```

You can parse the json using from_json method.

```
val testDF = df.withColumn("json", from_json(col("value"),jsonSchema ))
```

Answer (score 0):

`key1`, `key2`, and `key3` are not a filed. They are av value of key! The fields are `id`, `name`, `value` and `key` here and values of `key` could be dynamic and it's okay and there is no complexity here.